# javascript find in array different different value of properties and count each value

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 to start.
So i am trying to go over an array with the property of languages.
i want to count each different value of languages and then display the count with the language. I can do each of these seperate but I need to then be able to sort the languages from higher to lower.
something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/aQsuP/9/

```
  var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < this.array_elements.length; i++) {

    if (this.array_elements[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
        }
        current = this.array_elements[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
    document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.sort() will do the sorting. To use it , your result array should be a object array.
     Try this code

```
var array_elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e", "a"];

    var arrayOfLetters =[];
    var arrayOfLetterObjects=[];

    for(var i=0;i<array_elements.length;i++)
    {
        if(arrayOfLetters.indexOf(array_elements[i])>-1)
        {

            //arrayOfLetterObjects.push({"letter": array_elements[i],"value":arrayOfLetterObjects.value+1});
            arrayOfLetterObjects[arrayOfLetters.indexOf(array_elements[i])].value+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayOfLetters.push(array_elements[i]);
            arrayOfLetterObjects.push({"letter": array_elements[i],"value":1});
        }

        if(i==array_elements.length-1)
        {
            console.log(arrayOfLetterObjects.sort(function(a, b){

                return b.value - a.value;

            }));

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should explain your code so it's easier for others to understand the answer.